# Block direct access to folder, but grant access from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd

I've successfully installed a joomla website and was wondering if it's possible to access the admin panel through a subdomain redirect but blocking the direct access to 'administrator' folder.

In other words:

domain.net/administrator should be blocked (error 403 or other) and admin.domain.net should redirect to administrator folder.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the administrator folder or does it have to go through the sub domain? If you just want to hide the admin folder check out this extension http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/12254?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo3OiJqc2VjdXJlIjt9

Comment: thanks, i used adminexile plugin which does the same for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by installing AdminExile plugin:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711

Then i created a admin subdomain redirecting to /administrator?key=value and this solved my problem.